# How to hide todo notes without deleting them manually?

Tags: todonotes

I'm using the package `todonotes`. How can I disable the todo notes for printing my final document?
(I know it's possible, but I can't find it and I *don't want to* (manually) delete all my notes in the document...)

I've read the documentation, but I still have NO clue on what to type to disable `todonotes`. This is all I have in my preamble:

```
\usepackage{todonotes}
\newcommand{\td}[1]{\todo[inline]{#1}}
```

but commenting any of those will keep my note's text on the spot and just remove the formatting. I couldn't figure out what to type to fully remove that unless I go one by one and do it.

Comment: When you don't want your notes to be visible just change
\usepackage{todonotes}
to
\usepackage[disable]{todonotes}

Comment: Using the official methods is better, but you could just redefine the macro: `\renewcommand{todo}[2][]{}`.

Comment: how can I restore it easily, then? For me, an environment would work best to temporarily disable `todo`.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

I just got it: for notes not to be visible just change:

```
\usepackage{todonotes}
```

to

```
\usepackage[disable]{todonotes}
```

Answer (score 29):

You can also give it the `obeyDraft` option (`\usepackage[obeyDraft]{todonotes}`), so that it will display todonotes if your document is in `draft` mode and hide them if it isn't in `draft` mode. However, be aware that the `draft` mode also only shows bounding boxes for images, so that might be an issue.

Comment: My preferred option for `todonotes` is `obeyFinal`. With this option, todonotes will be disabled only in `final` mode.

Comment: to have the images displayed even on draft mode, you can use `\usepackage[final]{graphicx}`

Answer (score 4):

My preferred way is `\presetkeys{todonotes}{disable}{}` in the preamble, which also works in case `todonotes` has been loaded by some previous file, and you can't easily change its `\usepackage` line.

Answer (score 1):

An easy hack is to redefine command \todo somewhere at the top of document, e.g.

```
\renewcommand{\todo}[1]{}
```

This comes handy especially when your document is structured into multiple files, and you can not simply have control over \usepackage.

Comment: sometimes, `todo` has an optional argument, though :-/