# How to add todo notes?

Tags: todonotes

Is there a simple way to add todo notes to LaTeX documents ?

I would like to have these notes in red in the generated pdf and a simple syntax to write them.

Comment: todonotes package or marginpar?

Comment: In six years nobody mention the package [changes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285272/11604) ?

Answer (score 261, accepted):

There is a [`todonotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/todonotes) package that makes adding notes easy enough. They appear in the margins by default.

A simpler version, if you just want red text in the body of the text as notes is just to define a command `\myworries` that makes its argument red.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\myworries[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\begin{document}
Here is some text.
\myworries{But I'm worried about the text}
\end{document}
```

And then if you want to hide the comments, just add the line `\renewcommand\myworries[1]{}` below the `\newcommand`. This will hide all your notes.

A third option is to use LaTeX's own `\marginpar` command to put a paragraph in the margin. It's not great, but for little notes to yourself it's adequate.

Alan Munn, in the comments, has made me aware of another package [`todo`](http://ctan.org/pkg/todo) that seems to be simpler than `todonotes` but a little more powerful than `\marginpar`. Though I've not used it so I don't know for sure.

Comment: There's also the `todo` package, which works well.

Comment: @Seamus Thanks it is perfect, just one thing: is there a way to move the notes on the left side ?

Comment: @Patrick [For the todonotes package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5180/215). For marginpar do: `\marginpar[I'm on one side]{I'm on the other!}` So if you want just notes on the left side: `\marginpar[note goes here]{}` Note the empty braces.

Comment: it is also possible to have margin notes with different text on both sides at the same time

Comment: @Seamus I actually get notes on right side (and not inline) by using the \todo command. \todo{this is on right side} and the next line of text is underlined

Comment: @Patrick I use the middle option (the non-package option) myself, so you'll have to read the relevant manual (linked from the above links) to see how to get notes as you want them.

Comment: @Seamus yeah but I want to inform you that \todo makes notes on right side and not inline. So it is almost what I need. I will go through documentation now.

Comment: @Patrick OK. Thanks. Which package are you using? Both `todo` and `todonotes` define a `\todo` command...

Comment: you can also just use `\newcommand\myworries[1]{{\color{red}#1}}`, so you don't need xcolor.

Comment: Examples: https://www.overleaf.com/blog/619 and https://www.overleaf.com/help/41.

Comment: Is there anything like Google Docs / MS Word commenting system for LaTeX? Namely it allows different collaborators to answer and address others comments? I don't mean online solutions, but in the TeX code.

Comment: @Royi You could write comments to each other in the tex code. You and your collaborators could institute a proper version control system (eg using git and something like gitlab), but depending on the size of the project, that might be overkill.

Comment: I usually work with GIT on TeX. But I thought maybe there is something like an extension to this package which make it even close to Word / Google Docs experience.

Comment: One should not that this package may increases compiling time significantly: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8793/166952

Answer (score 290):

The `todonotes` package mentioned above can be customized to show various types of notes. It is also possible to create a summary of all notes, for example at the end of the document. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}                     % Dummytext
\usepackage{xargs}                      % Use more than one optional parameter in a new commands
\usepackage[pdftex,dvipsnames]{xcolor}  % Coloured text etc.
% 
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption,textsize=tiny]{todonotes}
\newcommandx{\unsure}[2][1=]{\todo[linecolor=red,backgroundcolor=red!25,bordercolor=red,#1]{#2}}
\newcommandx{\change}[2][1=]{\todo[linecolor=blue,backgroundcolor=blue!25,bordercolor=blue,#1]{#2}}
\newcommandx{\info}[2][1=]{\todo[linecolor=OliveGreen,backgroundcolor=OliveGreen!25,bordercolor=OliveGreen,#1]{#2}}
\newcommandx{\improvement}[2][1=]{\todo[linecolor=Plum,backgroundcolor=Plum!25,bordercolor=Plum,#1]{#2}}
\newcommandx{\thiswillnotshow}[2][1=]{\todo[disable,#1]{#2}}
%
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\todo[inline]{The original todo note withouth changed colours.\newline Here's another line.}
\lipsum[11]\unsure{Is this correct?}\unsure{I'm unsure about also!}
\lipsum[11]\change{Change this!}
\lipsum[11]\info{This can help me in chapter seven!}
\lipsum[11]\improvement{This really needs to be improved!\newline\newline What was I thinking?!}
\lipsum[11]
\thiswillnotshow{This is hidden since option `disable' is chosen!}
\improvement[inline]{The following section needs to be rewritten!}
\lipsum[11]
\newpage
\listoftodos[Notes]
\end{document}
```

This outputs the following text with notes:

[image: The text with notes]

And here is the summary page:

[image: The summary]

Notice the `\thiswillnotshow` note which is disabled using the `disable` option in the header. This can be used to turn off each type of note globally. Todonotes can also be used in the caption of tables and figures, though only provided that the `inline` option is used with these notes.

Comment: You can also add a todo note with an incrementing counter for each note, using the following code:


`\newcounter{todocounter}

\newcommandx{\todocount}[2][1=]{\stepcounter{todocounter}\todo[linecolor=YellowGreen,backgroundcolor=YellowGreen!25,bordercolor=YellowGreen,#1]{\thetodocounter: #2}}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what's "\newcommandx"? I only know \newcommand{...}

Comment: For disabling the notes when printing : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4830/how-to-hide-todo-notes-without-deleting-them-manually

Comment: This is not working. Results in `! Undefined control sequence.
\set@color ->\pdfcolorstack 
                            \@pdfcolorstack push{\current@color }\aftergroup...
l.1457 \color{black}` 

Also if fixed it looks like that: http://latex.informatik.uni-halle.de/latex-online/temp/olatex_2588192_1tcUlQhzFbfK.pdf

Answer (score 39):

see package [`cooltooltips`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cooltooltips). When the cursor is over "This text" the blue window pops up.

[image]

The source code for this example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cooltooltips}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\cool{\texttt{cool}}
\begin{document}

The \cool\ package enables a document to contain hyperlinks that pop
up a brief tooltip when the mouse moves over them and also open a
small window containing additional text.  \cool\ works only with
pdf\LaTeX\@.  Furthermore, the tooltips that \cool\ produces are much
less cool when viewed under older versions of Acrobat~($<7.0$) or the
current version of xpdf~(3.00) because they don't pop up the extra,
small window.  
\cooltooltip[0 0 1]{Example}{This is an example of a cool tooltip.  
Pretty cool, eh?}{http://www.ctan.org/}{Visit CTAN on the Web}{This text\strut} 
%
is an example of a cool tooltip (assuming
you're viewing this document with a sufficiently capable \textsc{pdf}
reader).  Move your mouse pointer over it and watch what happens.
Then, click on the link.  If your \textsc{pdf} reader is properly
configured it should launch a Web browser and send it to the
\textsc{ctan} home page.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 36):

Another possibility is the [`fixme`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fixme) package. It supports several ways of outputting the notes. You can have them directly inside the text, in the page margin, or as a list at the end of the document. You can even combine the methods.

It comes with support for different authors and different levels of severity. "Notes" and "comments" will simply be ignored if you compile the document with `final` option, while "errors" will produce compilation errors. In `draft` mode they will all be printed with different markup. Every author gets his/her own prefix, that is added to the note.

Comment: I use the fixme package and have defined several types of notes e. g. in red for important changes (missing content or content of document to check) and light green for "cosmetic changes" (text alignment could be better, etc.) - all in all I find the fixme package extremely useful

Answer (score 35):

To avoid the risk to submit the paper with the todo notes, I throw a warning, so that each todo appears as a warning when I compile. The command is

```
\newcommand{\todo}[1]{\textcolor{red}{TODO: #1}\PackageWarning{TODO:}{#1!}}
```

Comment: FYI `\textcolor` requires `\usepackage{color}` (or `xcolor`)

Comment: ^so you can replace `\textcolor{red}{TODO: #1}` with `{\color{red}TODO: #1}`

Comment: Note that for some reason for me this crashes rubber when the TODO has a certain length.

Answer (score 24):

The `todonotes` package suggested by MLC has colour built in.
The `\todo` command can take several options, including `color`. This voids the  need for making own commands if you just want to quickly colour your notes.
The list of options can be found here: [PDF](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes/todonotes.pdf)

Examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
\todo{default to-do}This is text that needs some attention.\\
\todo[inline]{Default inline to-do}
\todo[inline, color=green]{Green inline to-do}
\todo[inline, color=green!40]{Light green inline to-do}
\todo[inline, color=red]{Red inline to-do}
\todo[inline, color=red!40]{Light red inline to-do}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: todo latex colours]

Answer (score 11):

If you want the notes directly in PDF you may want to use PDF annotations with the pdfcomment package.

Take a look at the screenshots

- [How to annotate PDF files generated by pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17004/11166)
- [pdftooltip from pdfcomment package: Using LaTeX code in tooltip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120005/11166)

Comment: Could you please expand a bit, perhaps embed some of the screenshots in your answer? See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97483/8057 .

Comment: @krlmlr see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6306/how-to-annotate-pdf-files-generated-by-pdflatex/17004#17004 for a more detailed example

Answer (score 3):

Check out easy-todo on 
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/easy-todo

Comment: I am using this package due to its simplicity, although I have some minor issues with it. Just a notice: If you have strange issues with the content of your index. Uncomment the \usepackage{easy-todo} command for testing, if your issues are gone. It caused in my document class provided by my university, that index, table index and figure index got not displayed in the index. The creator of the document class said, it my may not be compatible with koma script. Once I don't use the easy-todo package, everything is fine. So I dont have to worry.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/kkew3/todo-tex

A Python3 solution that parses TODO notes in LaTeX source comments and outputs them on the terminal.

Sample from the GitHub page:

```
% myfile.tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Superchiasmatic neucleus is the primary clock % continue later: forgot what to write now
\end{document}
```

`$ todo-tex -lm` prints

```
./myfile.tex
    [TODO] line 3: forgot what to write now
```

> Supported TODO tags are todo, TODO, question, problem, continue here, continue later, continue ....

That list can easily be extended by editing the python script.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Hyperlinks can and eventually do break. Please edit your posting to convey (a) the gist of your answer and to point out (b) strengths of your solution as well as (c) any shortcomings or caveats. That way, readers of this site will be far more inclined to follow the link you've provided.

Comment: @Mico, I will edit Kevin's answer as I find it super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This adds the todo message into the PDF and also shows up as a warning during compilation. It can be used without arguments or with an optional message.

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\DeclareDocumentCommand\todo{g}{%
\def\@message{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{TODO}{TODO: #1}}
\textbf{\textcolor[HTML]{FF8811}{\@message}}
\@latex@warning{\@message}{}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Foo: \todo

Bar: \todo{message}

\end{document}
```