# Hiding marginal notes

Tags: marginpar

While writing I tend to add a lot of notes using `\marginpar`. Is there a way to hide them before printing a final version?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There a number of methods you can use. One way is to use 
yet another package such as the `todo`or you can simply define a command as shown below, which will perhaps also be more semantically correct for notes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor}

\def\noteson{%
\gdef\note##1{\mbox{}\marginpar[$\leftarrow$ ##1]{%
    \color{blue}$\leftarrow$ ##1}}}
\gdef\notesoff{\gdef\note##1{}}
\noteson
% Comment line above and uncomment to hide notes
%\notesoff
\begin{document}
\note{Adams disagrees on this issue.} This is some lipsum text
\lipsum[1-7]
\note{Check the reference out.} This is some lipsum text
\end{document}
```

You can switch them on and off using `\notesoff` or `\noteson`.

[image]

If you want to use the `todo` package check the post [How to add todo notes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9796/how-to-add-todo-notes)

Comment: I believe it should be `\gdef\notesoff{\gdef\note##1{}}` or it wouldn't gobble its argument, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 7):

You could use the `comment` package (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/comment). A little example (change `\includecomment{note}` to `\excludecomment{note}` to hide the margin note):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{comment}

\includecomment{note}

\begin{document}

text text text text
\begin{note}
\marginpar{a margin note}
\end{note}
text text text

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a great package. The only slight downside is having to surround all ```marginpar``` calls with an environment.

Answer (score 6):

Just redefine the command to do nothing:

```
\renewcommand{\marginpar}[2][]{}
```

Comment: I wouldn't redefine `marginpar` this way, as it may break other legitimate marginpars.

Answer (score 3):

I've been taking two approaches - one being to use the `opt` package, which ties output to tags that can be toggled:

```
\newcommand{\marpar}[1]{\opt{note}{\marginpar{\fnsize #1}\index{TODO}}}
```

Another way to suppress output of those modified marginpars if the `opt` environment cannot be used would be to hide the `\marginpar` inside a macro that never gets called.

```
\newcommand{\marpar}[1] {{\newcommand{\lastunprintedcommand}{\marginpar #1}}}
```