# What is a good package for taking note of draft ideas?

Tags: notes, draft

What is a good package for taking note of draft ideas, and have them emphasized in the output document? For example:

```
This is a very brilliant idea for a 
research topic \somecommandthathighlightsanotetoself{(Try
to find out exactly why this is a brilliant idea.)}
```

In the output document, I would like to see the note in red or any other color to call out my attention as I review my work. As a bonus, perhaps some note in the margins for additional attention-calling.

Comment: Also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124021/8057

Answer (score 29):

You can have a look at the `todonotes` package. It has some very simple yet quite customizable commands to add notes and stuff to your document. There is also a nice feature called `listoftodos` that lists all the `todo` fields that you set in the document.

Compare the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}
Some text... \todo{Some Todo stuff} Some more text

\listoftodos
\end{document}
```

[image]

The documentation of the package is quite short but shows some useful examples and tweaks.

But there is also a little drawback: as pointed out in the comments by T. Verron, `todonotes` is built up on `tikz` to draw its fancy note bubbles. This means that, depening on the number of notes you have in your document, the compilation process may be significantly slowed down.

Comment: If I use two `\todo{}` on the same line, the result is not so nice.

Comment: Thats true to some extent. But how often will this happen? And then there is also an ``inline`` option, that shifts the note from the margin into the text.

Comment: Note that this package makes use of `tikz` to draw the nice boxes. On long documents and slow machines, it may noticeably slow down the compilation process. Alternative solutions using simple `\marginpar` commands give less eye-candy, but are less expensive. YMMV

Answer (score 16):

If you use Adobe Reader, then there is also [`pdfcomment`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment). You can run `texdoc pdfcomment` in your terminal to read the manual. Like `todnotes` package, this package tries to emulate the commenting functionality found in some word processors.

This sample code is taken from the `example.tex` file provided with the package and some of the things that it can do.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\pdfmarkupcomment[author={Donald Duck},subject={Strikeout},color=red,markup=StrikeOut]{A little Test!}{Why is this repeated? This is a StrikeOut markup annotation} 

\pdfmarkupcomment[author={Donald Duck},subject={squiggly},color=Teal,opacity=1.0,markup=Squiggly]{Unfortunately the support of pdf annotations by pdf viewers is only partly available to nonexistent. The reference viewer for the development of this package is \texttt{Adobe Reader}.}{This is a Squiggly markup annotation}

\pdfmarkupcomment[id=300,author={Donald Duck},subject={highlight},color=yellow,opacity=1.0,markup=Highlight]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, 
placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, 
nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. 
}{This is a Highlight markup annotations with page break}

\begin{pdfsidelinecomment}[avatar=CaptainJack,subject={sideline},opacity=1,color=red,icolor=yellow,caption=inline,linebegin={/Butt},lineend={/Square},linewidth=3bp,linesep=1cm]{ ! Delete ! }
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{pdfsidelinecomment}

\vspace{2cm}
\definestyle{mathpopup}{author={},subject={},color=NavajoWhite,markup=Highlight}
\[
\begin{array}{c>{\displaystyle}c}
 \text{Bernoulli Trials} &
 \pdfmarkupcomment[style=mathpopup]{P(E)}{Probability of event E: Get exactly k heads in n coin flips.}%
  =
 \pdfmarkupcomment[style=mathpopup]{\dbinom{n}{k}}{Number of ways to get exactly k heads in n coin flips}%
  {\pdfmarkupcomment[style=mathpopup]{p}{Probability of getting heads in one flip}%
}^{%
    \pdfmarkupcomment[style=mathpopup,mathstyle=\scriptstyle]{k}{Number of heads}
  }%
 \pdfmarkupcomment[style=mathpopup]{(1-p)}{Probability of getting tails in one flip}^{%
 \pdfmarkupcomment[style=mathpopup,mathstyle=\scriptstyle]{n-k}{Number of tails}%
 }%
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remarkable package, which I hadn't seen before. And it works with my (non-Adobe) reader - [pdf-XChange viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer)

Comment: @Brent.Longborough I have to try pdf-XChnage viewer yet. I have uninstalled Adobe Reader for some time now.

Comment: It's Windows-only, I think, but, for what I do, I find it much less bloated than Adobe

Comment: @Brent.Longborough Yes. You are right. I might try it with `wine` in my linux machine for now. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Not so good in Foxit :( `\pdfmarkupcomment` appears as if I'd just used `\texttt{}`, while the `pdfsidelinecomment` shows up in the margin, with the box over the top of the text.

Answer (score 13):

I don't know if there is a package but I use this command

```
\def\alert#1{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
```

and then I simply type

```
text here \alert{in red} and foo
```

You can improve it to make use of some `\marginpar{}`.

Comment: I use a similar approach. If you want to typeset the document without notes then you can comment out `\def\alert#1{\textcolor{red}{#1}}` and replace it with `\def\alert{}`

Comment: Similarly here, though my `\warn` is slightly different: `\DeclareRobustCommand\warn[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{**CH**}}}{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{**CH**#1**}}}}` to allow an attention-grabbing mark even if I don't type anything.  I tend to have `%\renewcommand{\warn}{}` immediately following to make hiding easier by removing the `%`.

Answer (score 11):

Another option is the rather new [`fixmetodonotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fixmetodonotes) package. It is much more lightweight than `\todonotes` by using `\marginpar` instead of `tikz`, but contains many of its features, plus some more:

- Inline and margin placement
- Listing all notes through `\listofnote`
- Flexible customization
- Automatic placement of a DRAFT watermark on any page that contains notes (can be deactivated using the `nowatermark` package option)

The development version and an issue tracker can also be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/gioele/fixmetodonotes).

### Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fixmetodonotes}

\defnote{MARGIN}{inline}{\marginpar}

\begin{document}
  Some text... \FIXME{Some Todo stuff} Some more text
  
  It can also display \MARGIN{(Check if margin notes can be displayed
  with the new MARGIN note type)} notes.

  \listofnote
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of compilation]

Answer (score 3):

There's also the more mature [`fixme`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fixme) package, which I learned from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128221/make-fixme-notes-in-displaymath). My current favorite.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fixme}
\fxsetup{theme=colorsig}

\begin{document}
  Regular text
  \fxerror*{Issued by the fxerror command}
  continued here.
  \fxwarning{And another warning}
\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled output]