# make fixme notes in displaymath

Tags: displaystyle, fixme

I am using the `fixme` package. I observed the use of `\fxerror*` or `\fxnote*` inside `displaymath` yields errors.

I can write

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{fixme}
\fxsetup{theme=colorsig}

\begin{document}
\fxerror*{$\forall y \exists x \varphi(x,y)$}
{
\[
\forall y \exists x \varphi(x,z)
\]
}
\end{document}
```

with the expected result. But I sometimes would like to do something like

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{fixme}
\fxsetup{theme=colorsig}

\begin{document}
\[
\forall y \exists x \varphi(x,\fxerror*{y}{z})
\]
\end{document}
```

which doesn't work. Is it a (non)feature of the `fixme` package?

Second point, I would like it to work with the `align` environnement as well as with all the other math environnement provided in `amsmath`.

Comment: It has something to do with `\marginpar` use not permitted in math mode.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: @Jubobs I was a bit reluctant, since I ended up not using the answer. The solution is too particular, since as I commented it does not work with align. But I'll consider it!

Answer (score 4):

`fixme` uses `\marginpar` and this prevents using the commands in some places; a possible workaround is to substitute `\marginpar` for `\marginnote` from the [`marginnote`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/marginnote) package:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{fixme}
\fxsetup{theme=colorsig}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\FXLayoutMargin[3]{%
  \marginnote[%
  \raggedleft\@fxuseface{margin}\ignorespaces#3 \fxnotename{#1}: #2]{%
    \raggedright\@fxuseface{margin}\ignorespaces#3 \fxnotename{#1}: #2}}
\renewcommand*\FXLayoutMarginClue[3]{%
  \marginnote[%
  \raggedleft\@fxuseface{margin}\ignorespaces#3 \fxnotename{#1}!]{%
    \raggedright\@fxuseface{margin}\ignorespaces#3 \fxnotename{#1}!}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\fxerror*{$\forall y \exists x \varphi(x,y)$}
{
\[
\forall y \exists x \varphi(x,z)
\]
}

\[
\forall y \exists x \varphi(x,\fxerror*{y}{z})
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works fine! However this solution doesn't work for the 'align' environment... :-( Any idea?