# Custom dark theme with todonotes

Tags: texstudio

I started to use the dark theme [monokai](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108315/anyone-willing-to-share-his-her-custom-dark-theme-for-texstudio) which helps me when I have to sit a long time in front of my screen. I then noticed that with [the todonotes package redefined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9796/how-to-add-todo-notes) I can barely see the text, as shown in the following picture (Text with dark gray background):

I tried to modify the Texstudio profile but it did not change the dark gray background. Can any one help with this?

[image]

Comment: works here. Check the background color at `Options -> Syntax Highlighting -> Basic highlighting -> commentTodo`.

Comment: That did it. Can I accept a comment as an answer or do you have to re-write it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The relevant colour settings are found under

```
Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Syntax Highlighting -> Basic Highlighting -> commentTodo
```

You can edit the background and foreground colours to your liking.

[image]