# how to mark a word or a sentence to remember it in the futur

Tags: changes, markup, trackchanges, tags, remember

Me and my colleague have wrote a report using "Microsoft Word" and now we're migrating to LaTeX. While typing the document i figured out that some sentences (or words) must be changed.

i want to perform those changements and save their positions (along with the old content) so i can discuss them easily with my colleges and validate them (or reuse the old version).

is there a method\command in that can help in a such case ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Something like the package `todonotes` provides, perhaps?

Comment: It was already answered here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9796/how-to-add-todo-notes Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: see changes package https://www.ctan.org/pkg/changes

Comment: both `todonotes ` and `changes` packages work well, but `todonotes` better.
even that what i am searching is something like `todonotes` but it is very slow to compile even with a little paragraph !! very slow !

Comment: now it works fine, i think it was a problem with a missing package, it seems to be `pgf`

Comment: who can answer the question please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`todonotes`, `changes` packages do the work.

`todonotes` is better (my opinion).

Comment: Better ask the commentator to answer the question ... Why is `todonotes` better? For all people or only for you?  Please explain that better, otherwise it is only opinion based ...

Comment: yes right it is only my opinion! i'll mention it,

Comment: ok i'll ask commentator to answer