# Highlight text in editor window in TexShop

Tags: texshop

I want to highlight or mark some text in the editor window to remind me that I need to review it. Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the easiest way is just to include a comment before and after the text? Or include a reminder image in the resulting pdf (like https://imgflip.com/i/26ifi3).

Comment: Lool, nice image!

Comment: Nice image! The problem with adding a comment is that it tends to get lost in a file of many hundreds and thousands of lines.

Comment: Is adding notes to the PDF an option? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9796/how-to-add-todo-notes/9797#9797 Alternatively, if switching editors is an option, you could have a look at for example TeXstudio. It allows you to write magic comments like `%TODO review this`, and you can have all of these `%TODO`s listed in the structure panel on the left side of the editor. (Many editors, including TeXshop, have some form of support for magic comments, though I don't know which have exactly todo-comments implemented.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `todonotes` package. I have the following definition

```
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption]{todonotes}
```

If you want, you can even define different types of todo. Here is what I have, each with its own color:

```
%--------This section has to do with todo notes ----------------
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption]{todonotes}
\newcommandx{\intodo}[2][1=]{\todo[inline,#1]{#2}}
\newcommandx{\unsure}[2][1=]{\todo[linecolor=red,backgroundcolor=red!25,bordercolor=red,#1]{#2}}
\newcommandx{\change}[2][1=]{\todo[linecolor=blue,backgroundcolor=blue!25,bordercolor=blue,#1]{#2}}
\newcommandx{\info}[2][1=]{\todo[linecolor=OliveGreen,backgroundcolor=OliveGreen!25,bordercolor=OliveGreen,#1]{#2}}
\newcommandx{\improve}[2][1=]{\todo[linecolor=Plum,backgroundcolor=Plum!25,bordercolor=Plum,#1]{#2}}
```