# Add comments to text

Tags: comments

How is it possible to add comments in LaTeX and in the produced pdf show them with a different color?

Comment: Are you talking specifically about comments in the bibliography? If so are you using BibTeX (with `\bibliographystyle` as the title suggests) or `biblatex` (with `\usepackage{biblatex}` as the tags) suggests. Can you give more details what you are thinking about?

Comment: @moewe I mean that to had a command example \foc{I believe you could add precision metrics here}. This a comment from me during I read the text and I would like to add a comment with a color to see the author of the content.

Comment: But are you talking about the bibliography and BibTeX/`biblatex` or just about normal text in your document?

Comment: @moewe for normal text in the document

Comment: OK. Since this has nothing to do with the bibliography I remove the misleading "BibTeX" in the title and the `biblatex` tag.

Comment: You may want to look into the `todonotes` package. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9796/35864