# To-do on Latex document

Tags: layout

I am planning on keeping everything i do this year organized in a single latex project and want to have a little to-do list, ideally it would be in the top right corner of the first page and have a slightly tinted backgoud(see image)[image: page layout]
Is there a relatively simple way to do that or should i just put the list on the first page and start the project on the second?

Comment: does this correspond to your desires? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/178806/216067

Comment: See the above link in comments. But what I would do: Define an "notestomyself" environment that clears the page to recto when it ends, and resets the page count to 1 for the following material. Then I would define a boolean that turns the notes on or off. If on, the notes print, and the real document restarts at recto 1. If off, the notes do not print, and the document is as normal.

Comment: from the first look it seems those packages are rather for notes about the text i am writing and appear in the margins. ill have a deeper look at it tho, thank you!

Comment: The "secret weapon" might be package tcolorbox again: https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox . Perhaps you can or need to combine it with text-flow modifying packages: https://ctan.org/topic/text-flow .